# JavaScript not redirect

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dom-events

I am using the below JavaScript code for redirect to another page, but it is redirect to the default page. can any one suggest what should I do?

```
<input type="image" name="btnContinue" id="PromotionEntry1_imgbtnContinue" src="images/accept-button-orange.gif" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnContinue;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border:0;" /><br />
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? how do you perform redirect?

Comment: code you're showing do no redirect. Could you post redirect related code?

Comment: The code you posted is only the HTML-part which sends a Postback back to the server (reloads the same page you're on in this case). In javascript you use `location.href = 'http://www.google.com';` to redirect someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you simple want to redirect then use an hyperlink/anchor instead of

using `<input type="image" />`

normally input controls are used to send some data to the server and to do a postback.

You can use this

```
<a href="Give the link where you want to redirect">
    <img src="Your image path" />
</a>
```

The above HTML will redirect to the  href value of < a >.

Comment: Just as a note, putting spaces between your tag starts kinda invalidates the html.  < a > =/= <a>

Comment: Thanks Daedalus,   I use visual web developer for coding and it validates the tag with space, but its a good practice not to have unnecessary space as this will make the page heavy.